# CSS3 draw circle in middle of nav with overhand

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm not the greatest at CSS and I'm looking to do something like this:

[image: http://prntscr.com/bvewls]

I have a feeling I need to use `::after` and `content: ' '` to achieve this along with a `border-radius: 50%;`

```css
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
}
.nav::after {
  content: ' Hi ';
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 1px #222222;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 7.5em;
  width: 10em;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(40%);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav"></div>
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use a single HTML Element to achieve this effect. Check this out, though:

```css
#outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 225px;
  background-color:#ccc;
  position: relative;
}
#rounded, #leftbox, #rightbox {
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
#rounded {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  left: 50px;
}
#leftbox, #rightbox {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
#leftbox {
  left: 0;
}
#rightbox {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='leftbox'></div>
  <div id='rounded'></div>
  <div id='rightbox'></div>
</div>
```

Personally, I would use a transparent Image overlay, for backward compatibility, instead of this technique.